# iOS oneTimeCode not working on some devices

Tags: swift, one-time-password, sms-verification

[onetimecode-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMkce.jpg)

I tried to achieve the same as the above screenshot, but it shows sometimes, and sometimes doesn't.

Is there anyone who faced the same issue as me where iOS 12 or 13 doesn't show 2FA code from SMS on the keyboard.

in my code I set `textField.textContentType = .oneTimeCode`

also tried to `disabled` or `enabled` Password AutoFill in setting but still not help.

I shall appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a larger section of code so we can see what you've tried?

Comment: give more details what you have tried then only we can help  you

Comment: okay, I just added the screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a little bit late but, you have to check this setting on your non-working devices :

- Settings
- Passwords & Accounts
- AutoFill Passwords

If it's disabled, Apple will not read your messages on your `.oneTimeCode` fields, and they will not be displayed above the keyboard.